# How do I delete a part of a file name for a batch of files in Windows 8.1?

Tags: windows, command-line, batch, filenames

I have lots of files in a folder but they all start with a line of numbers and are separated from the actual file name by a "_"

For example:

123123123_filename.txt

456456456_filename2.txt

789789789_filename3.txt

I imagine you can run some sort of command so that it removes the characters before the " _ " and the "_" itself.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

If you aren't comfortable with PowerShell, you might want to take a look at free utilities like:  http://www.bulkrenameutility.co.uk/Download.php

Comment: I can use powershell.

Answer (score 0):

If you just wanted to remove the characters for a listing, you can put the following in a batch file substituting the relevant directory in place of `dirname`

```
for /f "tokens=2 delims=_" %%G in ('dir /b dirname') do @echo %%G
```

The `dir /b` produces a bare format directory listing (no heading information or summary). The `delims=_` indicates that the underscore should be used as the delimiter and the `tokens=2` indicates that you want what is after the underscore. See [FOR/F](http://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html) for a fuller explanation of how to use `FOR /F` in a batch file.

But if you want to rename the files without the numbers and underscore, in your example you have two files that would yield the name `filename2.txt` if the numbers and underscore were stripped away. What do you want done in that case? Or did you intend to use filename3.txt for the third file?

If what follows the underscore is a unique name, you could use the
following to rename the files, substituting the appropriate directory for *relevantdir*:

```
set dirname="relevantdir"
for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=_" %%G in ('dir /b %dirname%') do rename %dirname%\%%G_%%H %%H
```

In the above case, the first token, `%%G`, is what is before the underscore and the second token, `%%H` is what is after the underscore. I put them back together for the rename operation and preceded them with the directory since the rename command uses the syntax `RENAME [drive:][path]filename1 filename2`.

Put an `@echo off` as the first line in the batch file before the `set` command, if you don't want to see each rename operation as it occurs.

Comment: I meant to have the third filename as filename3.txt... whoops...

Comment: Now I'm just getting 100s of "The syntax of the command is incorrect." messages.

Comment: Can you double-check the commands that you placed in the batch file to make sure you have the same use of percent signs, quotes, etc.? If you omit the @echo off, what is the line you see that produces "the syntax of the command is incorrect" messages? I'd suggest copying a small subset of the files to another directory and performing a test on those first without the `@echo off` to see what line produced the error.

Answer (score 0):

```
powershell    
ls "*_*.txt" | %{mv -confirm:$false $_.name ($_.name).split("_")[1]}
```

powershell should be preferable on a Win8.

Answer (score 0):

PowerShell:
Assuming all files in folder need to be renamed (as OP implies):

```
$Folder = 'c:\path\to\folder'
gci $Folder | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name.Split('_')[-1] }
```